# $Df(x)=0$ for a differentiable function $f$ from $A \subset R^n$ to $R^m$ with $A$ open and connected, then $f$ is constant

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Let $A \subset R^n$ open and connected and let $f:A \to R^m$ a differentiable function. If $Df(x)=0$ for every $x \in A$, then f is constant in $A$.

This is what I did up to now:

Take $x_1, x_2 \in A$ such that the line segment that joins these two points is also in $A$. Define $\phi:[0,1] \to R^n$ as $\phi(t)=(1-t)x_1+x_2$. Then, $f(x_2)-f(x_1)= \int_0^1 \frac{d}{dt} f \circ \phi(t)dt=\int_0^1 D(\phi(t)).\phi'(t)dt$. But $D(\phi(t))=0$, which means $\int_0^1 D(\phi(t)).\phi'(t)dt=\int_0^1 0dt=0$, so $f(x_1)-f(x_2)=0 \implies f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. From here I don't know what else I can do. I mean, all that I know is that if I have $x_1,x_2 \in A$ such that $\overline {x_1,x_2}$ is in $A$, then the function takes the same value on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Here's what I could do with Eldredge's idea:

Let $x_0 \in A$ and let $U$ be the set of all points in $A$ that can be joined to $x_0$ by a finite number of line segments all contained in $A$. Then, it's easy to see that $f$ is constant in $U$: take $u,z \in U$, we know there are $l_1,...,l_n$ line segments that join $x_0$ with $y$. The extreme points of $l_1$ are $x_0$ and $y_1$, and $l_1$ is a line segment contained in $A$, then $f(x_0)=f(y_1)$. By the same argument, $f(y_i)=f(y_{i+1})$ where $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are the extreme points of the line segment $l_i$ for $2\leq i \leq n-1$ and with $y_n=y$. By induction one can prove $f(x_0)=f(y)$. Using the same argument, $f(x_0)=f(z) \implies f(y)=f(z)$.

Now I want to show that $U$ is an open set. Let $x \in U$, as $A$ is open, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(x,\delta) \subset A$. If $y \in B(x,\delta)$, then the line segment $\phi$ which joins $x$ with $y$ is also in $A$. Then, the polygon obtained from the composition of $\phi$ with the polygon that joins $x_0$ with $x$ is also contained in $A$ and it joins $x_0$ with $y$, this means $y \in U$, so $B(x,\delta) \subset U \implies U$ is open.

Let's prove that $U$ is a closed set in $A$. Take $u$ a limit point of $U$. There exists a sequence $\{u_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $u_n \to u$. As $A$ is open, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(u,\epsilon) \subset A$ and as $u_n \to u$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $n: N \leq n$, $u_n \in B(u,\epsilon)$. We know there is a polygon $A$ which joins $x_0$ with $u_N$ that is completely contained in $A$ and the segment that joins $u$ with $u_N$ is also in $A$, then $u \in U$. So, we have $U \subset A$ which is open and closed, as A is connected, $U=\emptyset$ or $U=A$, but $x_0 \in U \implies U=A$.

Answer (score 3):

Fix $x_0$ in $A$, and consider the set $U$ of all points in $A$ that can be joined to $x_0$ by a finite number of line segments (e.g. a piecewise linear path).  By your argument, $f$ is constant on $U$.  Show that $U$ is open.  Show that $A \setminus U$ is also open.  By the connectedness of $A$, we must have $U = A$.

Comment: I think I could complete the proof correctly with your ideas, thanks!