# $f : U \to \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $D f (p) = 0$ for all $p \in U$. Then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $f : U \to \Bbb R$
be a differentiable function such that $D f (p) = 0$ for all $p \in U$. Then $f$ is a constant function.

I am facing difficultly in doing this please help.

Comment: might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561803/dfx-0-for-a-differentiable-function-f-from-a-subset-rn-to-rm-with

Answer (score 1):

Let $p \in U$, and let $m=f(p)$.

Then $\{ m \}$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, so the preimage $f^{-1}(\{m\})$ is a closed subset of $U$, by continuity of $f$.

Let $a \in f^{-1}(\{m\})$. Choose $r>0$ such that $B_r(a) \subset U$. Let $y \in B_r(a)$, and define $\gamma: [0,1] \to B_r(a)$ as $t \mapsto a+(y-a)t$. So $\gamma$ parametrizes a line segment from $a$ to $y$. Then $\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))=Df(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t) = 0$ for all $t \in (0,1)$, so by Mean Value Theorem $f \circ \gamma$ must be constant. In particular $m=f(\gamma(0))=f(\gamma(1))=f(y)$, so $y\in f^{-1}(\{m\})$. Therefore $B_r(a) \subset f^{-1}(\{m\})$, so $f^{-1}(\{m\})$ is an open subset of $U$.

We showed that $f^{-1}(\{m\})$ is both open and closed in $U$, and thus by connectedness $f^{-1}(\{m\})=U$.